# CSV output file Error

Tags: ssis

I am exporting data from sql table to CSV file. Few of my columns in the table has "Comma(,)" separated data, while loading the same into CSV file, data has been splitted into two columns.

Example

data in Sql table

```
ename    desig    Industry
Roy      PM       Business,Analyst  
Rem      PL       Marketting and Production  
King     PM       Marketting, Analyst
```

while exporting the same data to CSv File it is coming in this way

```
 ename    desig    Industry
    Roy      PM       Business                       Analyst  
    Rem      PL       Marketting and Production  
    King     PM       Marketting                     Analyst
```

Since this is CSV format, it is delimiting after comma and taking Analyst as another column instead of same with Industry column.

My required output in CSV File

```
ename    desig    Industry
    Roy      PM       Business,Analyst  
    Rem      PL       Marketting and Production  
    King     PM       Marketting, Analyst
```

my FaltFileConnectionManager Settings are below

in General tab

```
Header Row Delimiter    {CR}-{LF}
```

Columns Tab

```
Row Delimiter   {CR}-{LF}
Column Delimiter  Comma{,}
```

I changed these setting , but still facing the same issue.

Comment: What are your settings for Text Qualifier?

Comment: Text Qualifies settings were <none>

Comment: Can you change the Text Qualifier to *"* (the double quotation mark) ?  This should qualify text fields with "" to follow the standard practice for CSV files of quoting strings so that imbedded commas don't cause a field break.

Comment: You state in comments and answer comments that you are using "|" delimiting but your column delimiter in the question above is ",".  Which one is the actual case will have a lot of impact on the answer.  Please check and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Since it appears from new information that you are not using a CSV (comma separated values) file, but are instead using a pipe delimited file, the issue appears to be that whatever is processing beyond this file is using both | and , as delimiters and therefore delimiting in the middle of the last field where there is an internal comma.  Since you don't want to use the industry standard where there are embedded comma's in a field and use a text qualifier on that field, then I am not sure what I can suggest without more definition about what you are using to test the file, what is processing the file after you are done etc.

Update your question with more information and I will refine my answer.  First guess without new information is that since you are using the .CSV name on your file that the comma handling is automatic by whatever is processing downstream.

**/EDIT**

Change the Text Qualifier to " (the double quotation mark), this should qualify text fields with "" to follow the standard practice for CSV files of quoting strings so that imbedded commas don't cause a field break.

Comment: HI William, when i tried using " as Text Qualifier, all the rows and columns are displaying with ".

Comment: Yes, that is a normal state for text fields in a CSV.  If you need, you can specify that only on text fields, or only on the Industry field.

Comment: How can i specify on Text fields.

Comment: In your Flat File Connection Manager, for each column where you want a text qualifier (in your case probably only the "Industry" column), you can set the property "TextQualified" to TRUE  for all other fields that are not likely to have an embedded column, set that property to FALSE.

Comment: After setting TextQualified true only to the Industry field, All the data under Industry columns are coming with "". like "Business,Analyst", "Marketting and Production". so on... By the way the column delimiter am uinsg is Pipeline delimiter.

Comment: Then if you are pipe delimited, why do you care if there is a comma in the last column?  I think that your original solution is correct, but whatever is processing your data after this step is wrong.  (Also don't use .CSV for this file since you are not using a comma delimiter and the .CSV implies that you are.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17072/discussion-between-user1348424-and-william-todd-salzman)

Comment: When i am importing the same as Comma Delimiter, i am getting the exact records. when using Pipeline delimiter facing issues. After my source query am using flat file destination.

Comment: Can't from here, my business prohibits external chat. email me directly and I will provide a summary as a new answer after we have resolved your issue.